# Not able to get the amazon RDS instances using AWS .NET SDK

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-rds

I'm not able to connect to my database in RDS from local machine....

Here is my code:

```
Amazon.RDS.AmazonRDSClient client = new Amazon.RDS.AmazonRDSClient(myPublicKey, myPrivateKey);

Amazon.RDS.Model.DescribeDBInstancesRequest instanceRequest = new Amazon.RDS.Model.DescribeDBInstancesRequest();

Amazon.RDS.Model.DescribeDBInstancesResponse instanceResponse = new Amazon.RDS.Model.DescribeDBInstancesResponse();

instanceResponse = client.DescribeDBInstances(instanceRequest);

Amazon.RDS.Model.DBInstance instance = instanceResponse.DescribeDBInstancesResult.DBInstance[0];
```

The `DBInstance` list is always empty i.e. the Count is 0. Whereas I know that I have RDS instances UP and running as I have created them using the management console.

**Also, when I prepare the connection string using the endpoint which I got from the RDS management console, I'm able to create table and all.**

I have provided access in the security group.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Im going to guess that your instance is not in the us-east region.

By default the SDK connects to us-east. If you want to connect to another region, you need to specify it on the AmazonRDSClient.

```
Amazon.RDS.AmazonRDSClient service = new Amazon.RDS.AmazonRDSClient(
  awsAccessKeyId,
  awsSecretAccessKey,
  new Amazon.RDS.AmazonRDSConfig().WithServiceURL(endpointUrl));
```

Possible values for endpointUrl are:

> https://rds.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (Default)
>
> https://rds.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
>
> https://rds.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
>
> https://rds.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: Nope... :(
The instance is in US-east region. Also when I see in the management console I found that the endpoint has **us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com** appended in the last..

Comment: I am stumped. I copied and pasted your *exact* code into Visual Studio and plugged in my credentials and I saw my RDS instance in us-east. Sorry!

Comment: I am really not sure why I'm not able to get the instances programmatically. While I can access the Database instance using the endpoint taken from management console by building the connection string. By this, I can conclude, at least access is not an issue. 

What do u say Joe?